# Override doesn't work the way it is supposed to

Tags: java, android

I have a class that extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` that is supposed to provide `actionBar` to other classes. Somehow when I override some methods, they aren't working the way they should. This is the original `overriden` method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainScreen.class);
        intent.putExtra("Back", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And here I `override` it in my `Activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Terms.this, CarDetailed.class);
        Log.d("ActionBar in Terms", "Home button pressed");
        intent.putExtra("Back", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The log says it is invoking home `button`, but somehow I am always redirected to `MainScreen.class`. What am I doing wrong?

**SOLVED**

I returned super method, that was my error.

Comment: Please paste the hole overriding method, you seem to forget the return statement.

Comment: Where's your return value?

Comment: I didn't copy all method.

Comment: You call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` in the `return` statement, which executes the superclass code

Comment: try adding this in your overriden method @ bottom  return true; so that the s/m identifies u have handled the event and dont go to the parent method

Comment: Yes! Sorry for stupid question.